# How does printf work on CUDA compute >= 2

Tags: c, cuda, printf, gpu

In the earlier days `printf` was not supported and we would either run CUDA programs using emulator or would copy back and forth the variable and print on host side.

Now that CUDA (arch 2 and greater) support `printf` I am currious to know how this work? I mean how internally the GPU `printf`s on the screen? What was the limiting factor in compute capability 1?

Comment: As a far as I am aware `printf()` requires an ABI. There was no ABI for sm_1x devices, one of the reasons presumably being the lack of a flat address space with generic pointers on the device (sm_1x only supported address-space specific pointers for shared, global, constant, etc address spaces). The current device-side `printf()` outputs to a ring buffer in the GPU's global memory, the contents of which is transferred to the host upon completion of the kernel. The ring buffer obviously can overflow; as far as I know the size is user configurable, check the Programming Guide.

Comment: You can set the size of the ring-buffer for device-size `printf()` with `cudaDeviceSetLimit (cudaLimitPrintfFifoSize, sizeInBytes)`. See the [ CUDA runtime API documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1gb8a22e29cc297634b0702db0b69f59e7)

Comment: The operation of device-side `printf()` is described in some detail in [section B.17. of the CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#formatted-output)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#formatted-output):

> printf prints formatted output from a kernel to a host-side output stream.
>
> The output buffer for printf() is set to a fixed size before kernel launch (see Associated Host-Side API). It is circular and if more output is produced during kernel execution than can fit in the buffer, older output is overwritten. It is flushed only when one of these actions is performed:
>
> ...
>
> Internally printf() uses a shared data structure and so it is possible that calling printf() might change the order of execution of threads. In particular, a thread which calls printf() might take a longer execution path than one which does not call printf(), and that path length is dependent upon the parameters of the printf(). Note, however, that CUDA makes no guarantees of thread execution order except at explicit __syncthreads() barriers, so it is impossible to tell whether execution order has been modified by printf() or by other scheduling behaviour in the hardware.
>
> The following API functions get and set the size of the buffer used to transfer the printf() arguments and internal metadata to the host (default is 1 megabyte):
>
> - `cudaDeviceGetLimit(size_t* size,cudaLimitPrintfFifoSize)`
> - `cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitPrintfFifoSize, size_t size)`